# How can I write at the end of line in a blank line of a letter?

Tags: formatting, letters

How can I write at the end of line in LaTeX? Suppose I want to say "thank you" in a letter and then put the name of the author right below it.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest:

```
\begin{flushright}
Sincerely,
\end{flushright}
```

However, this does add some spaces you may not want.  Perhaps:

```
\hbox to\linewidth{\hfil Sincerely,\hfil}
```

But in LaTeX this sort of thing should be handled by your class or package file; that is, you should be typing something like `\valediction{Sincerely}` and having LaTeX take care of where to put it.

What class are you using?  I'd suggest `newlfm` for letters; you can get this from your distribution's repos, or directly from CTAN.  I'd also suggest reading The Not-So-Short Introduction to LaTeX2e, which you can also find on CTAN.  It will give you the fundamentals for answering these questions on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside all due comments about logical versus physical markup, how would you just dash this off quickly in a one-off scenario?

If you have just one line, then the `flushright` environment will do the job.  If you have multiple lines, you probably want them left-justified among themselves.  This can be done by enclosing them in a `tabular`:

```
\begin{flushright}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    Sincerely,\\[0.5in]
    John Smith \\
    Vice President of Widgets 
  \end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
```

The `\\[0.5in]` leaves a half-inch space for a physical signature, etc.  Modify as desired.
Personally, instead of `flushright` I use a `\rule` of zero height to push the signature block a fixed distance to the right.

```
\noindent
\rule{4in}{0in}%
\begin{tabular}{l}
  Sincerely,\\[0.5in]
  John Smith\\
  Vice-President of Widgets
\end{tabular}
```

I do the same thing for the date and return-address blocks at the head of the letter, so that they all line up nicely.

Again, the idea of logical markup says we should be relying on a class to do this for us, or at least programming a class to our own ideals, rather than hard-coding this in every letter, but sometimes you just need something that's quick and works.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{l@{}}` will remove the space at the right end.

Comment: @egreg Good catch!